# Passing of any notification from sso app to other app which is redirected from sso in diff tab and both having diff origin/domain

Tags: push-notification, single-sign-on

How can we pass any notification from sso application to any other application which redirected from sso and opened in different tab and both sso and that application is having different domain or origin?

Tried with certain approaches like

1. Broadcast channel
2. Service worker
   But all are having limitations that applications should be have same origin/domain.